# Office add-in with user rights

Tags: excel, installation, vsto, excel-addins, installshield-le

I'm developping an Office Add-in for Excel using Visual Studio 2015 and C#.
This add-in was for administrators user only and it was working fine.
I recently changed this behavior and a regular user (without admin rights) can now install the add-in.

Using InstallShield Limited Edition I changed the properties:

- ALLUSERS from '1' to ''
- Require Administrative Privilege from 'Yes' to 'No'
- InstallDirectory from 'ProgramFilesFolder' to 'AppDataFolder'

At Excel startup the users have now a dialog asking to install the add-in.
The dialog the users receive looks like the one here:
[Unknown Publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZaAj.png)

- Why is the add-in not installed yet?

Despite the fact that the add-in should be installed by my EXE file, in this dialog the add-in is not signed however the EXE is signed.

Should I sign the VSTO file? I tried with signTool and cannot do it. Is that even possible?

Comment: You've got a lot of not-too-often used tags, I'm missing some higher level tags such as "Excel" (which I already added). Including them will increase the exposure of your question. Adding a runtime environment or programming language may also help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

- Put your VSTO in a trusted folder
- Did you try to sign your VSTO in VS ? `Solution Explorer -> Property -> Signing`

I faced that issue since a year, I understood that some paths are trusted some not.

For example **ProgramFilesFolder** is always trusted, I am not believing the same for **AppDataFolder**

In my situation I moved to **AllUser**.

Another advanced solution would be to think about [WIX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/main/), you will have full control over the deployment

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly this is not working for me. I still have the same issue. I have already done all my project with InstallShield, I would like to continue using it if I can. Another option could be to find a solution working for users without admin rights on the web and try to understand the differences compare to my project. I did not have found this yet, I'll try to do some more investigation. If you have another idea or a link to share I'm really interested.

Comment: In the ``Office Option -> Trust Center -> Trusted Locations`` you have to "user level" paths, try to put your manifest in one of that paths. Perhaps you should avoid to create subfolders.

Comment: I tested by adding manually the location of my folder with the manifest file (no subfolder). Unfortunately there is no difference, the pop up is still here

Comment: Another chance is to add ``Environment.CurrentDirectory`` in your addin startup then you proceed per-user install then you run the app and get its location. You could deploy your addin directly there or somewhere in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my own question...

Here is the link that helped me: http://amolpandey.com/2012/10/07/lets-deploy-vsto-deployment-via-regedit/
Many thanks to Amol Pandey for his tutorial.

If the link is not working in the future the idea is to update the registry and especially the registry keys which I didn't need before:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\SolutionMetadata